# Dopamine receptor count: Role and Measurement

Tags: receptor, dopamine

Can the Dopamine (DA) receptor count take a significant drop over the course of life or does it stay constant? I read that low D2 (Dopamine receptor type 2) receptor count does not cause Parkinson's Disease (PD) and has some interesting effects instead, but what abut low D1 (Dopamine receptor type 1) receptor count? What are its effects? All I found is [this](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2015/10/151006083855.htm). Is D1 receptor only related to motor activities?

I found [some research papers](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4090596/) on how to measure the DA receptor count, but are those tests publicly available and affordable? Is there any indirect way to determine D1 & D2 receptor count?

Disclaimer: This is not a self-help question, and PD is not my focus. I am trying to form a theory that requires easy way to measure DA level plus D1 and D2 receptor count, but sadly I am not part of any university with biology department to go seek advice from.

Comment: Welcome to BiologySE! Your question, for me, is a bit unclear. You could help people that are not experts in the field (but may still be willing and capable to help you with your question!) by (i) giving full name of abbreviations before using abbreviations and (ii) providing references (Wikipedia articles are sufficient for basic concepts) to both the major actors in your system (e.g. the receptors) and some claims. If you mention something like 'I found some research papers', people will definitively want to know which, so please provide the reference to these papers.

Comment: Sorry for the poor accessibility. I have edited the question. I am not allowed to most more than two links. So here is one link I wanted to post: Effect of low D2 receptor count: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2871784/.